# Can I nest Replace() AMPscript function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to nest an AMPscript function - Replace(). This should take a value and replace it based on what you designate in the function. However, I have two values I need to replace. The "@" symbol in an email address should be replaced by %2 and the "." symbol in the email should be replaced by %4.  This is for use in a URL string where the email address is appendeded to be passed and consumed. Currently I have this:

```
Set @email = [Email Address]

%%=Replace(Replace(@email,"@","%4"),".","%2")=%%
```

But it's only replacing the `@` and not the `.`.

Any ideas?

Here is the AMPscript variable block:

```
<!---ampscript
%%[
/* 101 */ Var @memberfirstname, @memberlastname, @refereefirstname, @refereelastname, @promocode, @rewardpreference, @amountpaid, @email
Set @memberfirstname = member_first_name
Set @memberlastname = member_last_name
Set @refereefirstname= referee_first_name
Set @refereelastname = referee_last_name
Set @promocode = promo_code
Set @rewardpreference = reward_preference
Set @amountpaid = amount_paid
Set @email = [Email Address]


/* 101 */
]%%
/-->
```

Due to client confidentiality I cannot post the entire URL string. Here is what it looks like without the actual URL:

```
<a href="https://url.example.com?c=promocode=%%=v(@promocode)=%%&email=%%=Replace(Replace(@email,"@","%40"),".","%2E"=%%"><img border="0" src="http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9015737461027473/m/1/btn-referee-reminder-apply.gif" width="115" height="32" alt="" longdesc=""></a>
```

Comment: Could you post your entire code block?  Reason:  if the SET is happening in an AMPscript block, like %%[ ]%%, there will be no need to have %%= =%% later on in the same block.  Also, it looks like your %4 and %2 are the opposite in your code compared to your question.

Comment: I just tried this exact code, and it worked perfectly.  Am I missing the issue?

Comment: It seems that due to the "." being replaced by "%2E", the system is returning the ASCII character "." as opposed to the string "%2E".

Comment: This section is missing a closing parenthesis - `%%=Replace(Replace(@email,"@","%40"),".","%2E"=%%`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about URL encoding and there is actually no issue with the functions as written.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies with the function itself -

Replace this:

```
%%=Replace(Replace(@email,"@","%40"),".","%2E"=%%
```

With this:

```
%%=Replace(Replace(@email,'@','%40'),'.','%2E')=%%
```

I just dropped this in my account and tested - the resulting link was:

```
https://url.example.com/?c=promocode=123&email=test%40test%2Ecom
```

Comment: The same string in my account ( parenthesis corrected - that was a typo) still yields the following when I click the link: ?c=promocode=X1X1&email=ashley.bisesti%40kobie.com where my email is ashley.bisesti@kobie.com.

Comment: It has something to do with the use of "%2E", because when I replace that with "dot" instead, it works. Is is just using the ASCII character and printing it to the URL?

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm trying it on chrome, and it's showing up as `%2E`. Also unsure why the `.` reverts and not the `@`.

Comment: Just tried again on chrome - `https://url.example.com/?c=promocode=123&email=test%2Ename%40test%2Ecom`. I think it's a browser issue.

Comment: By issue I just mean, the browser is interpreting the string automatically.

Comment: Yep - FF is rendering it, Chrome and Safari are not.

Comment: Kelly, Thank you so much. This is exactly the issue. Do you any insight into whether or not this might affect us trying to pass the variable through to the client? Would they see the "encoded" version or the rendered version?

Comment: The email is rendering the proper string, FF is just interpreting the ASCII code. It really shouldn't affect anything, but not sure what happens on the back end (post click) exactly.  Just would need some testing.

Comment: More than likely, I will close out this question as it doesn't directly have any issue.